# Vue: Toggle Button with Data from Child to Parent

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component, vuejs-slots

I have a parent component that has numerous containers. Each container has an image and some buttons.

I have over simplified the parent and child components below. When a button is clicked that is within the child component, I would like to toggle the class on an element that is in the parent container. **I would like to effect each image individually, not globally.** How do I do this?

parent:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div :class="{ active: mock }">
      <img src="/path">
    </div>
    <toggleButtons/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div :class="{ active: mock }">
      <img src="/path">
    </div>
    <toggleButtons/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import toggleButtons from './toggleButtons'
export default {
  name: "parent",
  components: {
    toggleButtons
  }
};
</script>
```

child:

```html
<template>
  <div class="switch-type">
    <a @click="mock = false">Proto</a>
    <a @click="mock = true">Mock</a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "toggleButtons",
  data() {
    return {
      mock: false
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: @Bulent, thanks, still learning here. I had read that emit event was a way to pass date from child to parent. But I just couldn't seem to get it working. How would I go about doing it in my example?

Answer (score 1):

Oversimplified example of how you can pass data from `child` to `parent`:

Child:

```
<a @click="$emit('mockUpdated', false)">Proto</a>
<a @click="$emit('mockUpdated', true)">Mock</a>
```

Parent (template):

```
<toggleButtons @mockUpdated="doSomething" />
```

Parent(methods):

```
doSomething(value) {
  // value will be equal to the second argument you provided to $emit in child
}
```

EDIT: (toggling the class for each individual container):

I would probably create a new component for the container `(container.vue)`, pass a `path` as a prop :

```
<template>
   <div>
     <div :class="{ active: mock }">
        <img :src="path">
     </div>
     <toggleButtons @mockUpdated="doSomething" />
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   props: {
       path: String,
   },
   data() {
       return {
           mock: false
       }
   },
   methods: {
       doSomething(value) {
           this.mock = value;
       }
   }
}
</script>
```

and then in `Parent.vue`, you can import the container component and use it like:

```
<template>
   <Container path="/path-to-file.jpg" />
   <Container path="/path-to-file.jpg" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with slots in your case. You need "emit event" to parent from button, and pass mock data to update img states. Slot is a very different thing. There are multiple ways to achive your goal. One way can be something like this:

parent

```
<AppImage v-for="img in imageData" :key="img.id" :image="img"/>

data() {
  iamges: ["yourPath1", "yourPath2"] 
},
computed: {
  imageData() {
    // adding ID is almost always a good idea while creating Vue apps.
    return this.images.map(x => {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      path: x
    })
  }
}
```

Image.vue

```
<img :path="image.path" :class={ active: mock} />
<toggleButtons @toggled=changeImageState />

props: [image],
data() {
  mock: ''
},
methods: {
  changeImageState(event) {
    this.mock = event
  }
}
```

ToggleButtons.vue

```
<a @click="toggleMock(false)">Proto</a>
<a @click="toggleMock(true)">Mock</a>

emits: ['toggled']
methods: {
  toggleMock(val) {
    this.$emits('toggled', val)
  }
}
```

Please read the code and let me know if you have any question.